# python how to combine nested values in a dictionary key:value

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I am using Python 2.7 and would like to merge nested values in a dictionary as follows:

```
list1 = {'V1': [['10', 'AND', '4'], ['4', 'AND', '2']]}
```

to a single set of values:

```
list1 = {'V1': ['10', 'AND', '4', '4', 'AND', '2']}
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do this with nested values in a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import itertools
list1 = {k: list(itertools.chain(*v)) for k, v in list1.items()}
# {'V1': ['10', 'AND', '4', '4', 'AND', '2']}
```

Comment: Glad it worked, please feel free to mark your question as answered.